# How to solve or bypass error websocket: origin not allowed

Tags: cordova, go, websocket, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

On my server I'm running gorilla web socket in go and I'm trying to connect from phonegap application with following javascript code:

```
var conn = new WebSocket("ws://IP:8080/ws");
```

but I'm getting this error: **websocket: origin not allowed** on my server.

Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Maybe another phonegap library or fix/update for this kind of connection?

I have tried many examples of phonegap script but non of them worked.

I would like to use that gorilla websocket plugin on my server but as things stand now that is not possible.
Thank you

Comment: can you have a http dump? especially compare to non-phonegap client

Comment: @JiangYD - how can I do that?

Comment: tcpdump in your server, to capture the port your server listening

Comment: @JiangYD - I have made "tcpdump port 8080", here is ss when phonegap tried to connect: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5tg7icq6gngd8dv/Screenshot%202016-05-09%2009.25.51.png?dl=0

Comment: according to [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) cross origin policy, there is no way you can send JS request outside your own domain.

Comment: Is there any other phonegap or ionic script which can connect to remote go gorilla websocket server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is - to implement your own CheckOrigin function in your websocket.Upgrader{} because default one checks server host and accept client connections only from same host

Comment: Is that ok if we look from security point? I am using on my server sequence and token authorization.

Comment: Origin header that is checker can be set manually, so yes, i dont think it will have huge impact on security

Comment: What is your advice, should I go with socket.io (which site is down in the moment:) ) or I can stay with web socket?

Comment: My advice is to correct server-side code to make things work

Comment: Thank you. I have implemented my own CheckOrigin function and now everything it's working. Do you have any other advice to improve security on server side?